# eclipse import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an existing Java project and I open it in eclipse.

Now I add a new package in it, and I create java files and write code in the new package.

However, when I try to import class from other existing packages, I failed.

Why?

Comment: which tool do you use for structure? Maven, gradle,..?

Comment: "I failed", can you be more specific about that part? can you show us your code, error message, configuration?

Comment: That's because you made some mistake somewhere. We cannot tell you more with the information you have given so far.

Answer (score 1):

Almost no info but I think that I know what happens:

Must be that the previous project's code is not in a source folder, instead I think that it's on a normal folder...

Look at Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source

A parent folder(s) of yoursource code folder(s) must be there.

If whit so little info I've help you to fix your problem you owe me a pizza.